# () operator in C

Tags: c, pointers, operators

I know that the "()" operator in C can behave either as a bracket operator or a function operator, My question is when will it behave as a bracket, and when will it behave as a function? For example, in the following code snippet

```
float (*ptr)(int)
```

We would read the above as follows, ptr is a pointer to a function that takes an int as a parameter and returns a float. My question is how does C know to interpret it this way?

Also, would this statement be legal:

`(*ptr)int` --> I would read this as saying ptr is a pointer to an int variable

Comment: How does it know how to interpret it that way?  Because no other way makes sense.  In other words, it's what the grammar stipulates.

Comment: Your confusion may lie in the fact that you're calling `()` an operator.  I don't think that is accurate terminology.  Parentheses are merely syntax in C.

Comment: It can also represent a "cast".

Comment: No "()" is described to be an operator in the book on C that I am reading.

Comment: Which book, so I can buy a copy and burn it?  Have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B.  Notice that the parentheses is not mentioned as a specific operator in the C language.

Comment: Are you sure it is not a C++ book?

Comment: "Operator" is an odd choice of words. Anyway, your confusion about the parsing rules is understandable, because distinct grammatical rules of C/C++ re-use similar syntaxes. Barring a few ambiguities, following the rules will give you exactly one interpretation of the program.

Comment: Operator Precedence Table of the book "C Traps and Pitfalls" by Koenig. This book is quite old though so giving you the page number probably would not do much good

Comment: Maybe the author is actually trying to lure you into traps and pitfalls by choosing odd terminology.

Comment: I mean you guys are all correct I am sure, this book made a mistake then which I guessis confusing my understanding now.

Comment: Parentheses are a grouping mechanism; in mathematical expressions, they are designed to override operator precedence.  With few exceptions, they take precedence over all other operator precedence.  But operator precedence has absolutely nothing to do with your question.

Comment: `operator()` exists in C++ but it is different thing. if you want answer for C only, please remove C++ tag

Comment: @RobertHarvey: But parentheses in the context of a function call mean something fundamentally different to those in the context of subexpression grouping.

Comment: I think I understand, the book was just trying to say that () precedence is above other common operators but it was not explicitly stating that () is an actual operator. I guess I interpreted it incorrectly. But with respect to my original question, I guess I just have to memorize how to read this stuff then? Its quite confusing

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Yes, that's what I said.  They're still not operators.

Comment: Robert Harvey: what about `a + b()`? In Haskell, for instance, juxtaposition could be called an operator, so calling C's `()` an operator makes some sense.

Comment: C doesn't have C++'s `operator` keyword, but it's not unreasonable to think of the `()` function call syntax as an *operator* that takes one pointer-to-function operand and zero or more additional operands that are passed as arguments. In the ISO C standard, the function call syntax is defined in section 6.5.2 "Postfix operators".

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Wikipedia doesn't define which C constructs are "operators"; see my previous comment and [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21009092/827263).

Comment: @KeithThompson: I've already read your answer, upvoted it, and posted a comment to it.

Comment: @Keith Anyway, I don't think that your meaning of "operator" is the way the word is commonly used.  Sure, you can probably make the case that it is an operator in the pedantic sense, but most programmers think of things like + and ~ when they talk about operators, not parentheses.

Comment: But my question was related to C, did not expect it to create such rawkus. Just trying to prepare for an interview and trying to get the basics on parsing expressions, grammar, and operators down. Sorry if the title is misleading but if I changed it to C++ it would not be representative of the language I have a question on.

Comment: Yes, sure. My mistake on that.

Comment: @Lee: He's asking about the `()` operator, not C++'s `operator` keyword. It's debatable whether `()` is really an *operator*, but it's not unreasonable to refer to it that way.

Comment: *sigh* If it's really a question about C, it's very unfortunately worded.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: You're right that it's not common, but for example the C standard clearly refers to cast *operators*. `sizeof` and `_Alignof` are also operators. The definition of *operator* in 6.4.6 is sadly ambiguous. (Not that it really matters a whole lot, I suppose.)

Comment: Im sorry for all the confusion everyone, I really did not think my question was so poorly worded. I did not know how else to pose the question, maybe I will think twice before asking a question on C again

Comment: @AyBayBay: Don't worry about it.  Your question is fine.  It even got an upvote.  We're all just crusty old curmudgeons; bear with us.

Comment: There are no operators in the sample code here ... not a one. Operators occur in expressions, but `float (*ptr)(int)` is a declaration, and `(*ptr)int` isn't legal C syntax.

Comment: "Your confusion may lie in the fact that you're calling () an operator. I don't think that is accurate terminology. Parentheses are merely syntax in C." -- But sometimes that syntax designates an operator (at least in C++, even if it isn't called that in C).

Comment: Also, in an operator precdedence grammar, `(` and `)` are treated as operators and are assigned a precedence.

Comment: "I guess I just have to memorize how to read this stuff then? " -- In the same way you memorized the syntax and other details of natural languages.

Comment: "most programmers think of things like + and ~ when they talk about operators, not parentheses" -- many if not most C++ programmers think of `operator()` as an operator, and rightly so.

Comment: "If it's really a question about C, it's very unfortunately worded" -- there's far worse at SO. If it bothers you that much you can edit it (or ask to have it edited, lacking enough rep to do it yourself).

Comment: "I really did not think my question was so poorly worded." -- It's not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parentheses, like commas, are used in a variety of different ways in C's syntax: function calls, expression grouping, declaration grouping, cast operators, delimiters for `if`, `for`, `while`, and `do-while` statements, delimiters for function-like macro definitions and invocations, and probably some others I'm not thinking of.

It's not entirely clear whether the function call syntax is really an *operator*. If it is, it takes one operand that's of pointer-to-function type, and zero or more operands that are passed as arguments. Function calls are described in section 6.5.2 of the ISO C standard, titled "Postfix operators", but some people are more comfortable thinking of a function call as a construct that's distinct from operators like `+` and `*`.

As for how that usage is distinguished from others, the idea is that the language grammar is (nearly) *unambiguous*.  There's a specific grammatical *production* that matches a function call:

```
postfix-expression:
    primary-expression
    postfix-expression [ expression ]
    postfix-expression ( argument-expression-list[opt] )
    [several more lines omitted]
```

When a compiler's parser processes a C source file, if it matches the production that defines *postfix-expression ( argument-expression-list<sub>opt</sub> )* as a *postfix-expression*, it recognizes a function call. Other uses of parentheses, such as in a cast operator, will not match that production, and so will not be treated as function calls.

[N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) is a recent draft of the ISO C standard.

Comment: `There's a specific grammatical production` -- which you can find in the C specification.  Or, you can just remember where everything goes.

Comment: @Keith Thompson You are wrong saying that "language grammar is unambiguous" There is some ambiguous constructions that are explained in a special section. For example it is true for C++.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Weasel wording added: "(nearly) unambiguous". But what special section (in the C standard) are you referring to?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Typedefs do create cases where the syntactic category of an identifier has to be resolved by referring to the symbol table (a `typedef` very nearly creates a new and possibly temporary keyword). Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: @ Keith Thompson I meant section "6.8 Ambiguity resolution" from the C++ Standard.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: That doesn't apply to C, which doesn't have "function-style explicit type conversions".

Comment: @Keith Thompson It seems is my mistake. I thought about C++.

Answer (score 0):

C has its own grammar as any other programming language according to which it analyzes the source code and produces correct constructions.

As for expression or declaration

```
(*ptr)int;
```

then it is incorrect. The correct declaration will be

```
int (*ptr);
```

Here int is a simple type specifier and ( *ptr ) is a declarator.

Comment: this makes sense then, a pointer variable should always have data type on its left side, indicating what type of data it points to, or in the case of a function, the return type of that function

Comment: @AyBayBay You can download the C Standard Draft that contains the description of the language itself and its grammar at the official site of ISO..

Answer (score 0):

It is the same as page 53 of K&R.  () [] -> have highest precedence.  It means that items within () or [] or the use of -> have the highest precedence.  It doesn't mean there is an () or [] operator.